# Using TLS in pjsua application

Tags: voip, pjsip, tls1.2

I am trying to use TLS in pjsua app, but i get an error here:

```
try{
      ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS, sipTpConfig);
} catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
}
```

The error is: Code: 171060 unsupported transport (pjsip_eunsuptransport).

Do you know something about it?

Comment: do you have the problem? or you solved?

Comment: Actually I did, but now when I am trying to make calls over TLS it says TLS connect() error: Connection refused [code=120111]. Do you have any idea about this?